# Drag and drop from outook to webapp

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, filereader

I'm coding a JSP with a drop zone where users can move any files (PDF, .XDOC, .XLS, ....) for uploading and I want to make it works with email too.

In my servlet, it  seems to be OK if the dragged email is at first drop on localdisk, then drop in the webpage. In that case i'm receiving some data.

Unfortunately, if it's directly drop from Outlook, nothinhg's happening...

Any suggestions to make it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to be impossible with html5 API & JS. I'll consider alternative as macro to upload the mails directly in DB from Outlook client.